# How to print price integer in drupal commerce cart block?

Tags: blocks, commerce

How to print price without decimals in drupal commerce cart block?
I found this code:

```
<?php
global $user;
$order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
$order_total = $wrapper->commerce_order_total->value();
$quantity = 0;
foreach ($wrapper->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
  $quantity += $line_item_wrapper->quantity->value();
}
?>
```

items. .

Code working correctly but price render with decimals.